# onmouseover function working, but onmouseout function is not?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onmouseover, onmouseout

right now I'm trying to make an overlay div appear when another element is hovered over, and I'm doing this with the `onmouseout` and `onmouseover` properties. In the element that is originally displayed, I have an h1 with a unique item code, and an image of the item. I also have another div that is set to `display: none` by default, with an id that is the code corresponding to the item. I want this div to show up on hover, and disappear when the mouse is moved away.

In the HTML code, I'm specifying functions to run on mouseover and mouseout, then in the Javascript for those functions, I'm first getting the h1 and its unique item code, then selecting the hidden div with the id as the item code to show or hide. The only difference between my show and hide functions is `style.display` since it is either 'block' or 'none'. The show function works perfectly, and the hidden div shows up. However, when I move my mouse out, the div isn't disappearing like its supposed to. Can someone help me figure out as to why?

```js
function showstatus(object) {
  code = object.querySelector('h1').innerHTML;
  document.querySelector(`#${code}`).style.display = "block";
}

function normalize(object) {
  code = object.querySelector('h1').innerHTML;
  document.querySelector(`#${code}`).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
{% for listing, specs in a_dict %}
<div class="list-item" onmouseover="showstatus(this)" onmouseout="normalize(this)">
  <h1 class="hidden">{{listing}}</h1>
  <img src="image link that I didn't include" class="item-thumbnail">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onmouseleave` instead of `onmouseover` as you are using it on a div.

```js
function showstatus(object) {
    code = object.querySelector('h1').innerHTML
    document.querySelector(`#${code}`).style.display="block";
}

function normalize(object) {
    code = object.querySelector('h1').innerHTML
    document.querySelector(`#${code}`).style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item" onmouseover="showstatus(this)" onmouseleave="normalize(this)">
       <h1 class="hidden">{{listing}}</h1>
       <img src="image link that I didn't include" class="item-thumbnail">
</div>
```

This is an alternate method of doing so:

```js
document.getElementById('div').onmouseover = showstatus(document.getElementById('div'))
document.getElementById('div').onmouseout = normalize(document.getElementById('div'))

function showstatus(object) {
    code = object.querySelector('h1').innerHTML
    document.querySelector(`#${code}`).style.display="block";
}

function normalize(object) {
    code = object.querySelector('h1').innerHTML
    document.querySelector(`#${code}`).style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<div id="div" class="list-item">
       <h1 class="hidden">{{listing}}</h1>
       <img src="image link that I didn't include" class="item-thumbnail">
</div>
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work though, I'm also not getting any error messages in the console or terminal

Comment: Could you please tell me the exact details of what doesn't work?

Comment: I have added an alternate method that I think would work in your case.

Comment: The onmouseleave isn't working so the function isn't running. So basically when my mouse leaves the div nothing happens

Comment: That would work, but in my actual html code, I'm running a for loop (with Django), so I can't do the id method